# How can I open another form after splash screen in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to c# and I am using windows forms.

I have 3 `Forms`:

- `SpalshScreenForm` with `progressBar` and `Timer`
- `MainForm`
- `ResultForm`

What I am trying to do is: I want to write `if` statement in `SplashScrreenForm` which checks if `Example.txt` file exists or not while `progressBar` is loading, and if the file exists I want to open `MainForm` and if it doesn't exist I want to open `ResultForm`.

As shown in code I run the program the `SpalshScreenForm` opens and after that it closes and then `MainForm` opens. The issue is that `ResultForm` never opens and it seems that the `if` statement does not get executed.

My question is : how can I open `SplashScreenForm` and check if the files exists, if the file exists I want to open `MainForm` and if it doesn't exist I want to open `ResultForm`. I am happy to listen to any new suggestions/ideas. Please help me thank you.

Program.cs Code:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }
}
```

MainForm Code:

```
public MainForm()
    {

        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Splash_Screen));
        t.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        InitializeComponent();         

        t.Abort();

    }
 public void Splash_Screen()
    {
        Application.Run(new SpalshScreenForm());
    }
```

SplashScreenForm Code:

```
 public SplashScreenForm()
    {           
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Increment(1);
        if(progressBar1.Value==100)
        {

            if (!File.Exists(@"E:\Example.txt"))
                {

                  ResultForm _ResultForm= new _ResultForm();
                  _ResultForm.ShowDialog();
                }

            timer1.Stop();            


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Program.cs`, change the last line to

```
Application.Run(new SplashScreenForm());
```

To make sure the Splash Screen is the startup project.

Next, change the `if` statement that checks for the existence of Example.txt in the SplashScreenForm code to

```
if (!File.Exists(@"E:\Example.txt"))
{
    ResultForm _ResultForm= new _ResultForm();
    _ResultForm.ShowDialog();
}
else
{
    MainForm _MainForm = new _MainForm();
    _MainForm.Show();
}
```

This ensures that either the `ResultForm` or the `MainForm` is shown at when the splash screen disappears.

Comment: @ Yurrit Avonds.  How about the Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Splash_Screen)); in the MainForm? do i have to delete it?

Comment: Yes, this would just show the splash screen again if you start the main form. Note that the splash screen will no longer run in parallel with any other form. Though, as long as your main form or result form does not take too long to load, this is not an issue.